# Rebooted EC2 now I can't call my express API

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-ec2, forever

I had an express API running on an EC2, which was being kept up by [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever).

I rebooted my EC2, restarted the app with forever, but the API is now unavailable.

It successfully responds when I do:

```
curl localhost:3000/helloworld
```

However, when I do:

```
curl http://ec2-bla-bla.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/helloworld
```

It throws an error saying:

```
Failed to connect to ec2-bla-bla.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com port 80: Connection refused
```

This is a public-facing API and I am unable to call it. I have no idea what it was about rebooting the EC2 that has broken the setup. Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you reboot, or shutdown, then restart? If the later, and you don't have an Elastic IP assigned, then the public IP changed and the DNS name you are using is no longer correct.

Comment: Also, if you setup `iptables` rules previously without persisting them, then they would have been reset.

Comment: Hi @MarkB, I just did a reboot, so the Elastic IP is still assigned. I also never setup any `iptables` rules. Having checked, all have the policy `ACCEPT`.

Comment: What maps a request on port `80` to the port `3000` that NodeJS is listening on? Were you not using `iptables` for that? Were you perhaps using Apache or Nginx as a proxy?

Comment: This I actually don't know. I didn't launch the app, I've just been managing it. Neither Apache nor Nginx is installed.

Comment: It sounds like you had an `iptables` rule to forward `80` to `3000` and it is now gone.

Comment: @MarkB you were totally right. Just added an `iptables` port forwarding rule. Can't thank you enough!!!

Comment: Make sure you look into persisting that rule this time.

Comment: I will do. Thank you for the tip! Really appreciate your help!